# Tcl script to search strings and store in variable

Tags: tcl

```
Loop = ( 
      {
        Value = ( 
          {
           {
            Key : 
            {
              A = "B";
              C = "D";
              Class = ( 
                {
                  section = "section_a";
                  Pairs = ( 
                    {
                      Name = "Ram";
                      Mark = "80";
                    }, 
                    {
                      Name = "Latha";
                      Mark = "70";
                    }, 
                    {
                      Name = "Mohan";
                      Mark = "90";
                    }, 
                    {
                      Name = "David";
                      Mark = "76";
                    } );
                } );
              Id = 1;
            };
            Absent : 
            {
              DAYS = "Two days";
            };
          }, 
           {
            Key : 
            {
              A = "B";
              C = "D";
              Class = ( 
                {
                  section = "section_b";
                  Pairs = ( 
                    {
                      Name = "Ram";
                      Mark = "30";
                    }, 
                    {
                      Name = "Latha";
                      Mark = "45";
                    }, 
                    {
                      Name = "Mohan";
                      Mark = "100";
                    }, 
                    {
                      Name = "David";
                      Mark = "76";
                    } );
                } );
              Id = 2;
            };
            Absent : 
            {
              DAYS = "Four days";
            };
          }, 
          } );
      } );
```

I am new to tcl script. I have a txt file in a above format. Using tcl script I have to store strings(section, Name , mark and Absent days) in a different variables to store in a csv file. 
I tried below code to search the word Key

```
set search "Key"
set file [open "Marks.txt" r]
 while {[gets $file data] != -1} {
    if {[string match *[string toupper $search]* [string toupper $data]] } {
        puts "Found '$search' in the line '$data'"
    } else {
        puts "does not match" 
    }
 }
```

It is working to find the word key and printing whenever it matches. It works for that line which has the word `Key`. But, here I want to find the word `Loop` then I want search for the word `Key` in side loop. If it sees the word `Key` then it has to copy some strings present in the loop to variables. The word `Key` will be repeated in the files multiple times. After the word `Key` there will be `{..}` all over there file has some content. The script has to read the content and store it in some variable.

Exp: The script need to find the word `Key` in the text file, then look for the 
section if present then `section_b` need to be stored in variable `temp1`(exp. `temp1`=`section_a`), Like wise:
If it sees `Ram` then `Mark` below the line needs to be stored in `temp2` (exp. `temp2`=`80`).
If it sees `Latha` then `Mark` below the line needs to be stored in `temp3` (exp. `temp3`=`70`).
then find id and need to to store the value 1 need to be stored in `temp4`(exp. `temp4`=`1`).
then `Days` meed to be stored in `temp5`(exp. `temp5`=`Two days`)

These temp values need to be written in the csv file everytime when it sees the word Key in the text file in below format.

```
section     Ram  Latha   id    Days
Section_a    80   70     1    Two days
Section_b    30   45     2    Four days
```

Can you help me in writing the tcl script to get this. Thank you.

Comment: That's a moderately complicated format you're trying to parse there…

Comment: It's more initial work, but if you're doing a lot with this file format, using the parser generators in tcllib to make a package to read the format might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing that awk is really good for:

```sh
awk '
    function quoted(string,     a) {
        split(string, a, /"/)
        return a[2]
    }
    BEGIN { OFS="\t"; print "section", "Ram", "Latha", "id", "Days" }
    $1 == "section" {section = quoted($0); delete marks}
    $1 == "Name" {name = quoted($0)}
    $1 == "Mark" {marks[name] = quoted($0)}
    $1 == "Id" {id = gensub(/;/, "", 1, $3)}
    $1 == "DAYS" {print section, marks["Ram"], marks["Latha"], id, quoted($0)}
' file
```

Translating that as a Tcl "one-liner", I'd write

```sh
echo '
    proc trim {str} {string trim $str {"}}
    puts "section\tRam\tLatha\tid\tdays"
    set fh [open [lindex $argv end]]
    while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
        if {[regexp -- {(\S+) = ("[^"]+"|\d+);} $line -> key value]} {
            switch -exact -- $key {
                section {set section [trim $value]; array set marks {}}
                Name    {set name [trim $value]}
                Mark    {set marks($name) [trim $value]}
                Id      {set id $value}
                DAYS    {puts [join [list $section $marks(Ram) $marks(Latha) $id [trim $value]] \t]}
            }
        }
    }
' | tclsh - file
```